# How to view code of predefined library functions in Python libraries?

Tags: python, quantlib

I use Quantlib and other packages for building a library of valuation models for derivative financial instruments in Python.

Some of the pre-defined functions I use a lot. I would like to understand the code underlying the functions in the libraries I use. Is there a way for me to do that? I am especially interested in the functions offered by Numpy and, Quantlib.

Comment: Both of those packages are open source, so what's the problem? Note that Quantlib is C++ and numpy has a lot of C, so if you only know Python reading them may not be too easy.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy and https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I just dont see how this answers my question. The links do not give me an overview of the code (or am i overlooking somerhing). I Also dont understand why there is no problem since the Packages are open source. Maybe i phrased my question wrongly. Let me restate: If i import numpy, what classes, functions etc are then available to me? And if i want to know the code (in c) behind it, Where do i look? Thanks in advance!

Comment: say you `import numpy`, then you can do `dir(numpy)` to see what is imported from the library. Does this help?